# KBibTex generating (unwanted) ligatures (Bug)

Tags: biblatex

I have an odd and frankly horrible problem. If I so much as open my (Biblatex) .bib-file in KBibTex, it inserts all kinds of German ligatures (st, ft, ...) **as characters**. That generates all kinds of problems down the line and is simply unwanted behaviour I can't seem to switch off. Has anybody else had this problem and/or a fix?

If there is no fix, then it is at least a warning to all to refrain from using this software. It happens by merely opening (no prompted saving), so it actively changes files by opening alone, leading to a lot of find/replace to make them usable again...

**Edit: Version 0.9 (Github, AUR) seems to be fixed in this regard.**

Comment: Does it only display the ligatures as characters or does KBibTeX actually save the file in a way that turns the ligatures into characters (even if you don't explicitly save the file)? Can you verify with a different text editor that the `.bib` file is actually changed? Maybe this is only a display issue. In any way you may want to contact the authors of KBibTeX about this. Currently this question reads more like a bug report that should be made via the official channels https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?product=KBibTeX

Comment: It actually inserts the ligatures as characters and it saves them without a prompt to save. I have verified, as I had to replace all the ligatures in a normal text editor to get back to beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=405504 and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=405645 this is a known bug that will be resolved in version 0.9 of KBibTeX. The bug report shows a way to test the development version of v0.9 already.

I could reproduce the issue with a build from the 0.8 branch of KBibTeX that identified itself as "near 0.8.2". The issue was not present in (the older) v0.8 from the Ubuntu 18.04 repository (`kbibtex 0.8~20170819`). Due to dependency issues I did not manage to compile the 0.9 branch on my machine so I could not verify that the issue is indeed resolved in the cases I observed.

Comment: Thanks for the info - didn't find the bug tracker via google, for some reason. 

Testing a bit more, I can confirm that the current Manjaro version still changes all ligatures if one enters a new title with ligatures, so entering a test entry leads to changes in the source file like "...der reinen Verﬆandesbegriﬀe".

Comment: Did we both just assume it was fixed only to encounter it again? (edits) ;)

Comment: @PaulBurgh Yes, I only found the bug after I had found out where to report bugs, a Google search does indeed not seem to produce any reasonable results. As far as I can see version 0.9 has not been released yet and 0.8.2 has the issue, so unless a hotfix for 0.8 is published you will probably have to wait until 0.9 comes out. Since the developer is aware of the issue and this is quite a serious issue I assume there is going to be a relevant release in the not too distant future, but you may as well nudge him about it if nothing happens in due time.

Comment: @PaulBurgh Well, I always had to trust the report status because I could not test v0.9. I just made that explicit in the edit to avoid the impression that I had verified the bug was gone.

Comment: I'll see if I find a way to nudge! I remember trying to get into the bug reporting mechanism and finding it rather difficult when I first encountered the issue maybe two months ago.

Comment: @PaulBurgh I know what you mean. I have somehow gotten the hang of and comfortable with GitHub by now, but all the (more established) bug tracking systems of other software project often look quite daunting to me.

Comment: In the end, it would seem that the issue lies with the distro repo (Manjaro community) containing a buggy developmental version, instead of the stable release (0.8.1). Installing 0.8.1 from source shows that this version also has no problems.